# Setting custom properties to custom open graph objects with Facebook iOS SDK

Tags: ios, facebook, object, action, facebook-opengraph

My scenario is the following:
I have a custom open graph object that sits somewhere at an url.
One of the string properties of that object, let's call it 'comment' it's not set in the meta tags of my object's page because I want to set it 'dynamically' from an iOS app.
I'm sharing my object with my custom action and also adding the 'dynamic' value for 'comment' but this value doesn't seem to be saved anywhere. I have created my aggregations so that it displays this property but it seems to ignore it.
Am I trying to do something that's not possible?

Comment: Same here. Documentation on this sucks.